# express-validator few custom validations check

Tags: express, express-validator

I need to check if user with passed `email` OR `login` already exists in database.

```
const userModel = new User();
const user = await userModel.findByLogin(req.body.email, req.body.login);

if (user) {
  req.checkBody('email', 'Email already in use').custom(value => user.email === value ? Promise.reject('Email already in use') : value);
  req.checkBody('login', 'Login already in use').custom(value => user.login === value ? Promise.reject('Login already in use') : value);
}

const errors = req.validationErrors();
```

`findByLogin` takes `email` and `login` and returns existing `user` or `null`. Email validation works as expected. But if I try to register user with unique `email` and existing `login`, it doesn't create any errors (`errors` is `false`).

Comment: Custom validator [link](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/custom-validators-sanitizers.html#custom-validator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just messed up with asynchronous validation. I cannot use `validationErrors` in my case, so I changed it to `getValidationResult` and it works fine now. Here is the result:

```
const userModel = new User();
const user = await userModel.findByLogin(req.body.email, req.body.login)
if (user) {
  req.checkBody('email', 'Email already in use').custom(value => user.email !== value ? value : Promise.reject('Email already in use')).withMessage('Email already in use');
  req.checkBody('login', 'Login already in use').custom(value => user.login !== value ? value : Promise.reject('Login already in use'));
}

const errors = await req.getValidationResult();
```